# Android Bring Back to Original State

Tags: android, fullscreen

This might be a noob question.
Actually I am trying to toggle the `Activity` Windows using a click.
With one click , my `Activity` goes FullScreen and the Next time I click , It should come back to Non-FullScreen State.

I made if Full Screen using:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but now I cannot return back to the NonFullScreen State.
How can I do it?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable full screen:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To go back to non-fullscreen:

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: But with this , THE NEXT TIME I TRY TO MAKE IT FULL_SCREEN, iT DOESNT WORK :(

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Check out my edited answer. Note that I use `addFlags()` instead of `setFlags()`;

Comment: Bingo , I was just about to post this, I also corrected it :D
Thanks Anyways :)